# Finding exact position in NSOutlineView from IBAction

Tags: objective-c, nsoutlineview

I have an `NSOutlineView` and I'm trying to insert a new row into when a button is pressed in the view above.

The view appears in the outline view but in the wrong location. I suspect this is down to the nested nature of the outline views.

I have the below code in my custom `NSTableCellView`.

```
- (IBAction)reply:(id)sender {
    CustomOutlineView *ov = (id)[[self superview] superview];
    CustomTableCellView *cell = [[CustomTableCellView alloc] init];
    DataSource *ds = (id)ov.dataSource;

    long row = [ov rowForView:self];

    [ds.commentsArray insertObject:cell atIndex:row+1];
    [ov reloadData];
}
```

This will insert the view to below the parent. What I'm looking to do is insert it below the view where the button is located.

So my question is as follows: How exactly do I work out where to insert my new view when working with NSOutlineViews.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't seem MVC of you to be maintaining an array of TableCellViews in the datasource.  And regardless of that, an outline view uses a tree where the cell is at an IndexPath, not an Index.  You may get NSTableView methods to work because it's NSOutlineView's superclass, but that doesn't mean they'll do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I figured I was being silly. I'll go back and rethink this.

Comment: NSOutlineView is clunky.  NSTreeController is even worse, and it's the NSArrayController equivalent for NSOutlineView.